# PHP PDO Select speed concern

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to pass an array as an argument to my PHP function.
This array can consist of up to 100K rows or more.
What the function does is it check (SELECT) from a table if those records exists or not.

The function run well, but right now I can only test it with one record passed as a argument.

My concern is the processing speed as many users can run this process simultaneously. I also
worry the whole site down because of my (maybe) inefficient function.

This is the code:

```
$result = _is_already_registered_user($email_addr);
//$email_addr is array, can consist 100K records or more

function _is_already_registered_user($email) {
    $servername = "myserver";
    $username = "myuser";
    $password = "mypassword";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mytable", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        return "error connect to database";
    }

    $email_explode = explode('\n', $email); 
    $result = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<=count($email_explode)-1; $i++) {
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) from user WHERE email = '$email_explode[$i]' LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result[$i][0] = $email_explode[$i];
        if($stmt->fetchColumn()) {              // found
            $result[$i][1] = '1';
        } else {
            $result[$i][1] = '0';
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Is that good enough? Is there any ways to improve it?

Thank you, Guys!

Comment: 100k individual queries? I would think that that's going to take quite a long time to run. Even if each query takes 0.1 ms it would take 10 seconds. Can you say why you need to check 100k email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to ensure speedy database performance is to define an index (in your case on the 'email' column). This will ensure that the DB does not have to perform full table scans but rather can fetch the given email address directly through an index lookup.

Comment: The "email" colomn is a primary key, is that enough? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a primary key automatically has a unique index defined for it. Assuming email is a PK, you're fine.